# Any obvious flaws in this CAML Query?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, caml, sharepoint-api

I am querying a sharepoint list via the web service api. Calling the service through the API requires sending an `XmlNode` object that represent the CAML query. With everything else exactly the same, these are two different queries I'm attempting to send (obtained via the `XmlNode`'s `InnerXml` property right before they are sent to the API):

```
<!-- This one works fine -->
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" /> 
            <Value Type="Text">304</Value> 
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>

<!-- This one fails with a Soap exception (which I've seen before when searching
     for an invalid field, but the first one calls the exact same field). -->
<Query>
    <Where>
        <In>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" /> 
            <Values>
                <Value Type="Text">304</Value> 
                <Value Type="Text">303</Value> 
                <Value Type="Text">302</Value> 
                <Value Type="Text">301</Value> 
            </Values>
        </In>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

I'm new to CAML queries, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious about how `In` statements work, but all the examples I've viewed seem to have this exact format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of SharePoint are you using ? The IN element seems to be valid only in SharePoint 2010. (According to this article: http://www.lushpedia.com/post/Alternative-of-In-Clause-for-CAML-Query-for-SharePoint-2007.aspx)